# How do i get the value of a bootstrap form helper phone input with jquery

Tags: jquery

Take a look at my code (html)

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe487daffffc42d2b4c2

Take a look at my code (javascript)

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20394ea4684df7ff0b43

Why can I not get the value of the phone number field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
phone = $('#phonenumber').val();
```

to:

```
phone = $('#phonenmber').val();
```

You want to ask for the value of the `<input>` not the `<div>`.